# Boolean not storing correctly?

Tags: java, boolean

The program that I've written isn't storing the boolean `late` correctly and sets it as true every time regardless of what's been typed in ("Yes" or "No"). Because it's storing it as true every time the program runs as if the customer has had a late payment every time. I just can't peg what I'm missing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final double PCT1 = .02; // Platinum
    final String PLATINUM_LEVEL = "Platinum";
    final double PCT2 = .025; // Gold
    final String GOLD_LEVEL = "Gold";
    final double PCT3 = .03; // Silver
    final String SILVER_LEVEL = "Silver";
    final double plusInterest = 0.005;
    double interest = 0;
    double interestOutput = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name; //  Name of customer
    String level; //  Membership level of customer
    String lateTrue = "Yes";
    String lateFalse = "No";
    String latePayment;
    boolean late = false;
    double lateFee = 25.00;
    double percentToPrinciple;
    double percentToInterest;
    double minPayment = 0;
    double balance;
    double princePay;
    double monthlyPay; //Last Payment late?
    System.out.println("Was the last payment made late?");
    latePayment = keyboard.next();

    if (latePayment.equals(lateTrue)) {
        late = true;
    }
    else if (latePayment.equals(lateFalse)) {
        late = false;
    } // Interest Rate Calculation
    if (level.equals(PLATINUM_LEVEL)) {
        interest = PCT1;
        if (late = true) {
            interest = interest + plusInterest;
            interestOutput = 2.5;
        }
        else {
            interestOutput = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (level.equals(GOLD_LEVEL)) {
        interest = PCT2;
        if (late = true) {
            interest = interest + plusInterest;
            interestOutput = 3;
        }
        else {
            interestOutput = 2.5;
        }
    }
    else if (level.equals(SILVER_LEVEL)) {
        interest = PCT3;
        interestOutput = 3;
    } // Monthly Payment
    monthlyPay = PCT3 * balance; // Payment to Principle Calculation
    princePay = balance * interest; // Minimum Payment
    minPayment = princePay + monthlyPay;

    if (level.equals(SILVER_LEVEL)) {
        if (late = true) {
            minPayment = minPayment + lateFee;
        }
    } // percentToPrinciple
    percentToPrinciple = 100 * (princePay / minPayment); // precentToInterest
    percentToInterest = 100 - percentToPrinciple;

if (late = true) {
    System.out.println("Interest rate for late payment: " + interestOutput + "% per month");
        if (level.equals(SILVER_LEVEL)) {
            if (late = true) {
                System.out.printf("Late fee: $" + "%3.2f\n", lateFee);
            }    
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Interest rate: " + interestOutput + "% per month");
    }

    } //  End public static void main method
} //  End public class Discount
```

Comment: @Stígandr Don't be afraid to suggest the edits yourself in the future. The 2 rep reward is in place for a decent reason.

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statement, you are **assigning** `true` to `late` and not comparing to it. Do this instead:

```
if(late == true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, COMPLETELY overlooked that.

Comment: @Cytozen Please use [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) from now on, it would greatly help from making typographical mistakes like these. Also, don't write `variable == true` or `variable == false`, just use `variable` or `!variable` already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you're checking if latePayment.equals(lateTrue) is true, but the variable lateTrue holds a string and is not a boolean.

Comment: Right, that if statement was to assign the boolean value true or false. I had just set the boolean to true after it had been assigned already instead of comparing it with "==" using "=" wrongly.